# How to obtain PKCS8 RSA Private Key from string / obtain RSA key pair from XML

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, rsa, pkcs#8

Recently, I have to convert an java project related to rsa/des encryption into an iOS project. The provided rsa key strings are from x.509 and PKCS8, however, security.framework only support PKCS12. I've been searching for libraries a long time, but it seems that currently there are not any objective-c libraries that support PKCS8. (I don't want to use Chilkat for some reasons)

The origin version of the project was written in C# which uses an XML string to generate RSA public/private key pair. I guess that generate rsa key pair by myself might be a better solution. Thus, my question is, are there any methods to convert rsa xml data to standard pem key format? Or there are other existing libraries that supports PKCS8?

Hubert

Comment: Do you need to convert it programmatically from iOS or you can do it compile time and embed it in the app bundle in the format iOS supports?

Comment: It's not required to convert it programmatically in iOS. Thus, I can do it manually and past the key to my code, its ok.

Comment: by the way, the rsa xml file looks like this: <RSAKeyValue>
<Modulus> … </Modulus>
<Exponent> … </Exponent>
<P> … </P>
<Q> … </Q>
<DP> … </DP>
<DQ> … </DQ>
<InverseQ> … </InverseQ>
<D> … </D></RSAKeyValue>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can convert the keys at compile time, you can use [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs8.html) to do so that it can convert between virtually any certificate / private key formats. Then you embed the certificates in the application bundle in PKCS12.

Comment: I've convert the RSA Private Key Xml file to common PEM file and are trying to put it into my project. I'll post the solution if solved, thanks!